# Place multiple HTML elements hovering over each other in center of a parent element using CSS and mostly relative properties?

Tags: html, css

I need this markup to then use in an animation. This animation should use relative values almost anywhere to scale without breaking and look similar anywhere. `display: flex` and its aligns and justifies work wrong in my situation, so I went here to ask.

This is my markup:

```css
.a-parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.a-child {
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #0099ff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a-parent">
  <div class="a-child"></div>
  <div class="a-child"></div>
  <div class="a-child"></div>
  <div class="a-child"></div>
  <div class="a-child"></div>
</div>
```

How could I center all 5 `a-child` elements over each other to make it look like this?

[image: desired result]

**EDIT:** fixed my html, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use position relative on the `.a-parent` and absolute on `a-child` and align children horizontally and vertically center in the parent.

```css
.a-parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
}

.a-child {
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #0099ff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="a-parent">
  <div class="a-child"></div>
  <div class="a-child"></div>
  <div class="a-child"></div>
  <div class="a-child"></div>
  <div class="a-child"></div>
</div>
```